# JavaScript JSON.parse UTF-8 problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest

I have a page that makes a request to a php file via AJAX, and that AJAX file displays a JSON which is the response, and I've got some issues with it.

It results that my page uses UTF-8 charset in order to display some special chars, etc; my AJAX file used ANSI encoding by default but then I decided to change it to UTF-8 to get the correct symbols with it too, but when I use JSON.parse it throws me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token", (if the AJAX file is encoded as UTF-8), then I change to ANSI 
and it works great, I don't know why JSON has that behaviour.

When I look at the output (xhr.responseText) both from ANSI and UTF-8 are identical (I'm not even using special chars in UTF-8).

Maybe JSON.parse doesn't accept response from UTF-8 files (something that I don't believe) or do I have to set a header in order to fix that? What do you guys think about it? Thank you..

Answer (score -1):

I had faced same problem. I used following encode functions instead of default encode function. It gives me perfect result

```
function json_encode_utf8($arr) {
  array_walk_recursive($arr, 'encode_utf8');
  return mb_decode_numericentity(json_encode($arr), array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
}

function encode_utf8(&$item, $key) {
  if (is_string($item))
    $item = mb_encode_numericentity($item, array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
}

$group_members = array('Matthias  Schöbe');

$group_members_json = json_encode_utf8($group_members);
```

Comment: These are PHP functions, consider giving a full JS answer to a JS question.

Comment: You have to do this on serverside